# How to run Cobertura code coverage with SBT build

Tags: scala, jenkins, sbt, code-coverage, cobertura

I want to configure cobertura code coverage for litespeed playframwork which run on SBT build.
If any one has done integration of cobertura code coverage for play framework with SBT(scala build tool), please share the details. I was not able to find any source for cobertura with SBT.

First i need to achieve cobertura with SBT.

Also later i have to integrate Junit, Code coverage(cobertura) with Jenkins.

Thanks for your help.